# App windows getting shorter and shorter in macOS

Tags: window, macos-mojave

I like to keep the active window maximised and typically use ⌥⌘F with Spectacle to quickly achieve that.

Often times, however, typically when docking/undocking or resuming the OS from sleep (can't pin it to a specific cause), all windows appear to have been resized automatically and their height is slight shorter then the available screen, leaving a gap at the bottom, between the window and the dock. If *untreated*, the gap keeps increasing.

Any ideas why that might be?

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Try it without Spectacle for a few days, to eliminate that as the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the reason for this issue.

When a new icon appears in the dock, e.g. when opening a new app, the dock itself sometimes automatically resizes itself to make room for it. This depends on how many icons are already displayed and whether the new one will fit or not.

As the dock height changes, the gap appears between its top border and the bottom border of the windows that were previously maximised.

I have now made the dock smaller, with plenty of space for new icons to be added without the need for the dock to resize itself.